# Xamamarin iOS 10 simulator not working

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I'm using VS 2015 with Xamarin and my application not run within iOS emulator anymore. I've updated XCode to the 8 version and Xmamarin to the latest version.
[image]

[image]

Looking at the output of the VS I've got this log row:

```
The installed Xamarin.iOS (version 9.8) on the Mac MacBook-Pro-di-Dario.local (192.168.1.230) is not compatible with the local Xamarin.iOS 10.0.
```

I've read about update Xcode and Xamarin to fix this problem but I should be already updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a Windows machine with a build host?

If so..from the message it sounds like you need to update Xamarin.iOS and XCode on your build host `MacBook-Pro-di-Dario.local`

Comment: Yes, I'm using a Windows machine with a build host. I've updated the Mac with Xcode 8 but it doesn't work. I'm updating to Sierra right now and I'll see. Xamarin is updated to the last version...